# Не работает jquery validation ajax

Tags: jquery, валидация

```
$("#contactForm").each(function() {
    $(this).validate({

        rules: {
            name: {required: true},
            email: {required: true},
            phone: {required: true}
        },

        messages: {
            name: "Введите ваше имя!",
            email: "Введите ваш email!",
            phone: "Введите ваш телефон!"
        }
    });
});
```

```js
$("#contactForm").submit(function() {

    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://piccolosolo.ru/form_download.php',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $("#messageResult").html(data);
        },
        error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#messageResult").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: У вас две формы с одинаковым ID?

Comment: да, но это попапы с разным html содержимым + свой php обработчик. без валидации формы  работают

Comment: `.each()` после `$("#contactForm")` лишен всякого смысла, ибо по селектору по ID (`#`) выбирается 0 и 1 элемент, но никак не два. `.submit()`, аналогично, будет работать только для первой формы. Правильным подходом в этом случае будет замена ID на класс.

Comment: Полный воспроизводимый пример кода должен быть в вопросе, а не на стороннем сайте. На это есть некоторые причины. Но даже если оставить в вопросе только представленный JS-код, полный пример (без всякий картинок, меню и прочего - только формы) стоит разместить, например, на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: добавил https://jsfiddle.net/a2media/77z112Lj/

Comment: 1. Я вижу только одну форму. Или её одной достаточно для воспроизведения проблемы? 2. В представленном коде есть синтаксическая ошибка (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`). Так что код попросту не рабочий. 3. После исправления синтаксических ошибок нужно в fiddle подключить jQuery (для этого надо нажать на кнопку "javascript" с изображением шестерёнки) и добавить плагин Validate (или как он там называется) в "External Resources" (меню слева).

Comment: да, одной достаточно. сделал форк https://jsfiddle.net/a2media/5o98jdov/ , добавил validate.js . С синтаксисом есть пробел, убрал лишние скобки. Теперь в сафари отправляет но без проверки

Comment: jQuery вы так и не подключили в fiddle. Вас не смутили ошибки в консоли в fiddle? Но да ладно - подключил сам. Вот тут я и заметил, что вы неправильно производите `submit` формы (игнорируя результат валидации). Посмотрите на [обновлённую версию fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5o98jdov/1/).

Comment: спасибо! вижу submitHandler, разбираюсь почему работает в фидл а на сайте форма не вызывется

Comment: На здоровье. Да, в документации по Validate рекомендуется использовать именно `submitHandler`. В принципе, ничего больше я в коде не трогал, поэтому в чём может проблема при переносе этого кода на сайт сказать не могу.